# Is Ubuntu 16.04 supported by HP360 gen8 Using RAID

Tags: server, lubuntu, hp, raid, canonical

I am having a problem. I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 server on HP DL360 Gen8 using RAID, the problem is that after I finish installing it does not boot to the O.S. Looks like HPDL360 GEN8 does not have support using RAID in ubuntu.

Comment: That machine has a certificate for 12.04 so anything after that will be supported. Did you follow the comments here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10849/ ?

Comment: @Rinzwind, yes In bios I select the  Legacy SATA, but the problem is that it will not use RAID,I tried to remove 3 HD only 1 hd i remain,it did not boot to the O.S

Comment: @Rinzwind The link you included is broken; it returns `404 Not Found` as of this writing. Do you have an updated URL?

Comment: start from the base url: https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Untill now only upto Ubuntu 14.04 is supported. So I am afraid if you want things to work you have to downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Then do the following:

Add this PPA to your repository:

```
ppa:hp-iss-team/hpvsa-update
apt update
```

Then install the driver hpvsa

```
apt install hpvsa
```

Comment: Have you tried successfully install ubuntu 14.04 in HP DL360e GEN8 using RAID ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am running an HP DL360 Gen9 using RAID 1 with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with no problems whatsoever.

In my opinion there should be no problems with the Gen8.

I did the RAID setup loosely following these setup instructions:

-https://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/101016393